# How to add two different animation with different duration in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have the following code animate any `widget`

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimElasticOut extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int delay;
  final Key key;
  final startAnimation;

  AnimElasticOut(
      {@required this.key,
      @required this.child,
      this.delay,
      this.startAnimation});

  @override
  AnimElasticOutState createState() => AnimElasticOutState();
}

class AnimElasticOutState extends State<AnimElasticOut>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animation;
  int duration = 1000;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: duration));

    animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: controller,
      curve: Curves.elasticOut,
    );

    if (widget.startAnimation != null) {
      if (widget.delay == null) {
        controller.forward();
      } else {
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: widget.delay), () {
          controller.forward();
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaleTransition(
      child: widget.child,
      scale: animation,
    );
  }
}
```

Sample usage

```
AnimElasticOut(
                        key: counterElasticOutKey,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 35,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 15),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                Icons.add_alarm,
                                color: Colors.amber,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Counter(
                                key: counterKey,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

I start the animation using the following code.

```
counterElasticOutKey.currentState.controller.forward(from: 0);
```

Now it animates the widget nicely.

I also have another code to reverse the animation.

```
counterElasticOutKey.currentState.controller.reverse();
```

What I want is to use another animation while reversing. Also, some other duration.
For example, I want `Curves.easeInOutCubic` as an animation curve with a duration of `milliseconds: 500`

How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b526ea62/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation_controller.dart#L314

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about `reverseDuration` until now. But how can I use any other animation in reverse?

Comment: by calling `reverse()` method your animation will go down (towards value of zero)

Comment: Yeah. But I need to use another animation curve while reversing. By default, I have set `Curves.elasticOut` curved animation. I want to use `Curves.easeInOutCubic` while reversing

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b526ea62/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animations.dart#L389 why dont you read the sources or at least [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/CurvedAnimation/reverseCurve.html)?

Comment: Thanks man. I'll try to read the sources next time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property `reverseDuration` in `AnimationController` & `reverseCurve` in `Animation<T>`

```
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    );

    animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: controller,
      curve: Curves.elasticOut,
      reverseCurve: Curves.easeInQuad,
    );
```